# How do I write that $f(n)$ should equal $x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Let's say I create a function $f(n) = 3n - 1$; how can I later write that the function $f(n)$ *should* be equal to some value $x$? My research is telling me this is written as $f(n) \equiv x$ which says that $f(n)$ is equivalent to $x$. However, is this misleading in any way? It seems that "equal by definition" would be a better fit here writing it as $f(n) := x$ or $f(n) ≜ x$.

---

How do I write that the result of a function $f(n)$ should equal some value $x$?

Comment: Saying $f(n) \equiv x$ says to me that $f$ is the constant function with value $x$, i.e. $f(n) = x$ for all $n$. This is obviously misleading if $f(n) = 3n - 1$, as $f$ is not a constant function in this case. I'm not really certain what you are actually asking here. Are you looking for a symbolic way of saying $f(n)$ should attain the value $x$ for some $n$?

Comment: Wait, so $3n+1$ isn’t the definition of $f(n)?$ You need to be more specific here about things. $:=$ is used for defining a function.

Comment: @TheoBendit that's precisely what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my apologies; I'm not familiar with it, and as such am trying to learn.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Then, I would usually recommend saying it with words, along the lines of what I said above, unless it's buried in a long string of symbolic arguments. If you wish to use symbols, you could say $x \in \operatorname{Range} f$ (or whatever notation for the range you prefer).

Comment: I had never seen $f(n) ≜ x$ before.

Comment: @Yorch It's another way of writing "defined to be", much like $:=$. It doesn't seem to be particularly popular in my experience, but I have seen it before.